Safari Can't Open Downloads Directly
I am not sure why but recently when I download PDF, PNG, HTML, Safari prevents me from opening it in the download button to the right of the search bar. I have to go to finder to open it manually. Any solutions?


What is your macOS version? Did you first have this problem right after an update to macOS or Safari? To what folder are the files being downloaded?

MacBook Pro 14″, macOS 14.5. It started in October, not sure if it was after update since auto-updates. The download location is the default Downloads folder.

Please boot in Safe Mode and test, then reboot as usual and test again. Update your question with the results.
